# Call static C# method from C++

Tags: c++

I have created a .netmodule from a C# class library. I am trying to call into a static C# method in the .netmodule from my C++ code. I cannot figure out the syntax (my C++ is weak)to do so. Here is my C# method.

```
namespace MyModule
{
    public static class VersionChecker
    {
        public static string GetDllVersion()
        {
            //do some stuff
            return version;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried both solutions below...

```
MyModule::VersionChecker.GetDllVersion();
MyModule::VersionChecker->GetDllVersion();
```

but I am getting the following error on both lines...

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

Or

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'
```

Can anyone tell me how I can call the static method `GetDllVersion` from my C++ code?

Comment: Try `MyModule::VersionChecker::GetDllVersion();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, all references to static members (or types) use `::`:

```
MyModule::VersionChecker::GetDllVersion();
```

Comment: Ah thats it, thanks for the answer. Such a simple one, but my C++ skills are terrible :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MyModule::VersionChecker::GetDllVersion();
```